# Data Division in MATLAB Neural Network Train Command

Tags: matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, training-data, nntool

While training a neural network in MATLAB I am using "train" command. Is this command auto divide the data into training, testing, and validation sets or we have to divide the data manually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. But we can divide the data manually, if we want to. `net.divideFcn` and `net.divideParam` fields of the net object should be used:

```
t=0:0.05:8; x= sin(t);
net = feedforwardnet(3);
net.divideFcn= 'dividerand'; % divide the data randomly 
net.divideParam.trainRatio= 0.7; % we use 70% of the data for training 
net.divideParam.valRatio= 0.3; % 30% is for validation
net.divideParam.testRatio= 0; % 0% for testing
net = train(net,t,x);
plot(t,x,t,net(t));
```

Here is an example of a manual data division:

```
net.divideFcn= 'divideind'; % divide the data manually
net.divideParam.trainInd= 1:100; % training data indices 
net.divideParam.valInd= 101:140; % validation data indices 
net.divideParam.testInd= 141:161;  % testing data indices
```

Comment: As I am having 'x' as input variables and corresponding to that input variable I have 'y' target variables. So while choosing 'dividerand' both variables will be divided simultaneously or they will be randomized separately?

Comment: Simultaneously, of course. It makes no sense to divide them separately.